# How to strip characters within a filename?

Tags: sh

I am having trouble on stripping characters within a filename.

For example:

```
1326847080_MUNDO-Cinco-Cosas-Que-Aprendimos-Del-Debate-De-Los-Republicanos-1.xml

1326836220_PLANETACNN-Una-Granja-De-Mariposas-Ayuda-A-Reducir-La-Tala-De-Bosques-En-Tanzania-3.xml
```

This is the output I want:

```
1326847080_MUNDO-1.xml

1326836220_PLANETACNN-3.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.xml
do
    j=$(echo $i | sed -e s/-.*-/-/)
    echo mv $i $j
done
```

or in one line:

```
for i in *.xml; do echo mv $i $(echo $i | sed -e s/-.*-/-/); done
```

remove `echo` to actually perform the `mv` command.

Or, without `sed`, using bash builtin pattern replacement:

```
for i in *.xml; do echo mv $i ${i//-*-/-}; done
```

Answer (score 0):

`rename` to the rescue, with Perl regular expressions. This command will show which moves will be made; just remove `-n` to actually rename the files:

```
$ rename -n 's/([^-]+)-.*-([^-]+)/$1-$2/' *.xml
1326836220_PLANETACNN-Una-Granja-De-Mariposas-Ayuda-A-Reducir-La-Tala-De-Bosques-En-Tanzania-3.xml renamed as 1326836220_PLANETACNN-3.xml
1326847080_MUNDO-Cinco-Cosas-Que-Aprendimos-Del-Debate-De-Los-Republicanos-1.xml renamed as 1326847080_MUNDO-1.xml
```

The regular expression explained:

- Save the part up to (but excluding) the first dash as match 1.
- Save the part after the last dash as match 2.
- Replace the part from the start of match 1 to the end of match 2 with match 1, a dash, and match 2.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late reply , but i saw it today :( .
I think you are looking for the following

input file :: 
cat > abc

```
1326847080_MUNDO-Cinco-Cosas-Que-Aprendimos-Del-Debate-De-Los-Republicanos-1.xml
1326836220_PLANETACNN-Una-Granja-De-Mariposas-Ayuda-A-Reducir-La-Tala-De-Bosques-En-Tanzania-3.xml
```

code : (its a bit too basic , even for my liking)

```
    while read line
    do
    echo $line ;
    fname=`echo $line  | cut -d"-" -f1`;
    lfield=`echo $line |  sed -n 's/\-/ /gp' | wc -w`;
    lname=`echo $line | cut -d"-" -f${lfield}`;
    new_name="${fname}-${lname}";
    echo "new name is :: $new_name";
    done < abc ;
```

output ::

```
1326847080_MUNDO-Cinco-Cosas-Que-Aprendimos-Del-Debate-De-Los-Republicanos-1.xml
new name is :: 1326847080_MUNDO-1.xml

1326836220_PLANETACNN-Una-Granja-De-Mariposas-Ayuda-A-Reducir-La-Tala-De-Bosques-En-Tanzania-3.xml
new name is :: 1326836220_PLANETACNN-3.xml
```